# C# gmap control can't be used in .NET Core 6.0

Tags: c#, winforms, google-maps, .net-6.0, ggmap

As I looked up, I think this lib is not compatible with .NET Core 6.0 but my project also works on it. When I try to add gmap form component into a form, I get an error:

[image: ERROR]

It says Gmapcontrol component couldn't be created.

What to do ?

Comment: There is no such thing as ".NET Framework 6.0" - it went from ".NET Framework 4.8" to ".NET Core 1/2/3" and then just ".NET 5", ".NET 6", and now ".NET 7".

Comment: thanks for information but it doesnt make sense with my problem i think.

Comment: there says  .Net Core 3.1, 5.0, 6.0 support added on its page but i cant even load the lib from nuget

Comment: It says **Could not load file or assembly System.Data.SQLite - Version 1.0.98.0** - do you **have** that assembly on your system? Or might you have a different (earlier) version of it, only?

Comment: later i found that is not the official lib when i try the first lib i want to it cant even be load from nuget